# At what point in the morning prayer should one answer kedusha?

Tags: halacha, tefilla, prayer-book, shacharis-morning-prayer, hefsek-interruption

If one finished saying Krias Shema in Shacharis at the same time as the congregation is starting their silent shmone esray, my understanding of Shulchan Aruch O"C 109:2 is that one has to delay and say kedusha together with the congregation before starting his own shmone esray. How should this be done practically (should he slow down his prayers or stop at some point and wait)?

Answer (score 2):

Shulchan Aruch ([OC 66:9](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/tursa.aspx?a=oc_x437)) says he should wait at *shira chadashah* to answer *kaddish* or *kedusha*.

Siddur *Derech HaChaim* [writes](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=42975&st=&pgnum=20) more explicitly:

> If he was reading *shema* when the congregation began praying the *Amidah*, if he can start and finish the *Amidah* (until *Elokay Netzor*) before the *chazzan* reaches *kedusha*, such that he will be able to say [*kedusha*] with the congregation, he should pray [now]. If not, he should not pray [now], rather he should wait at *shira chadashah*.
>
> *[...]*
>
> And likewise if he knows the congregation will say *barchu*, and he has not yet heard [the recital of *barchu*], *[...]* if he knows he will not be able to finish the *Amidah* before the congregation will say *barchu*, he must wait at *shira chadashah* until he hears *barchu*.

Comment: This is referring to a case where he's already at the end of the last blessing, and saying he shouldn't finish off before answering. How do you know he should purposefully get up to there and wait? Maybe he should wait earlier on in the blessing or before starting the blessing or something else? Maybe he should just say the blessing exceedingly slowly? Indeed waiting for a while at any point in a blessing is actually potentially problematic as a Hefsek.

Comment: Can you explain why you are proposing waiting silently Kedei Sheyigmor Et Kullah which is not allowed (OC 65:1)? Or is this assuming a short wait?

Comment: @DoubleAA Voluntarily waiting is permitted according to your source (OC 65:1). In any case, that's talking about the *Shema*, whereas here the wait would be during the blessings after *Shema*.

Comment: that's not true

Comment: @DoubleAA "קראה סירוגין דהיינו שהתחיל לקרות והפסיק בין בשתיקה בין בדיבור וחזר וגמרה אפילו שהה כדי לגמור את כולה יצא אפילו היה ההפסק מחמת אונס. הגה: ויש אומרים דאם היה אנוס והפסיק כדי לגמור את כולה חוזר לראש והכי נהוג"

Comment: right. [15char]